# SELECT * FROM $table WHERE anything = $x?

Tags: mysql

I have very simple question.

Is it possible to select * from a table where ANY of the values in a data set is equal to my search term?

e.g.:
The search term is "car", and I have a database with the columns x, y and z.
The sql_query should search for the word "car" in all 3 columns, and not just in one of them (where X = car).

Is this possible?

My suggestion would be: `SELECT * FROM $Table WHERE % = $x` - is that right? I don't have the option to test it yet.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you need to specify each column. As a side note, such queries are often a sign that you could optimized your table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM $table 
   WHERE column1 
   LIKE '%$search_word%' or column2 LIKE '%$search_word%' or  column3 LIKE '%$search_word%'
```

Comment: I thought about the same, but I was hoping there was a smarter way. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable T
WHERE T.x = 'yourTerm'
    OR T.y = 'yourTerm'
    OR T.z = 'yourTerm'
```

This query will only return the rows where one of the columns is **equal to the searched term**. If you want to get every rows with columns that **contains the searched term**, here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable T
WHERE T.x LIKE '%yourTerm%'
    OR T.y LIKE '%yourTerm%'
    OR T.z LIKE '%yourTerm%'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I thought about the same, but I was hoping there was a smarter way. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ChristianHennig The problem here is the structure of your table, there is no other way to get the results you want with this data structure

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE CONCAT(col1,',',col2,',',col3) LIKE '%search_term%';